# TP Link WN 725n driver

Tags: wireless

I dual boot ubuntu with windows. since my internal wifi card is damaged i have to use  TP Link WN 725n.

how to install its drivers without having any internet connection

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0408:20f5 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

ubuntu-gnome-15.04-desktop-i386

that also doesnt work

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: entered lsusb but nothing happened

Comment: What did you expect to happen? It should give output that will help to identify the chip. You need to press Enter, then copy the text from terminal and paste it to your question.

Comment: this was the output

Comment: PLEASE [edit] YOUR QUESTION and add output there.

Comment: What is Ubuntu version?

Comment: Please do not replace the whole content of your answer with edits.

Comment: What "that" does not work? Please follow the answer very carefully. Since you post your comment always to wrong places, you probably do something wrong with the driver installation.

Comment: I don't know if you tried this, but I had to turn off the computer and turn it back on again after installing the USB to get it to  be recognized by Ubuntu.  However, it is automatically recognized when I plug it in now.

Comment: everything working fine now i rebbt and insert usb 2-3 times it starts working...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download these files and copy them to your Home folder.

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.10.1_all.deb

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/archive/master.zip

Then run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
unzip rtl8188eu-master.zip
sudo dkms install ./rtl8188eu-master
```

Then reboot and insert the dongle. It should work.

Comment: when i type lspci output was different

Comment: You do not need to type `lspci`. You need to install the driver the way I described.